Unable to open .grd file on R using raster
I have downloaded a .grd file from IMD website https://www.imdpune.gov.in/cmpg/Griddata/Rainfall_25_Bin.html
It is described as 0.25 x 0.25 Binary file.
Below is MWE
# Package names
packages <- c("raster", "sp", "sf", "data.table", "reshape2", "lubridate", "dplyr", "maptools", "rgeos", "rgdal", "ncdf4", "ncdf4.helpers", "ecmwfr", "chillR", "exactextractr", "akima", "bowerbird", "httr")
# Install packages not yet installed
installed_packages <- packages %in% rownames(installed.packages())
if (any(installed_packages == FALSE)) {
  install.packages(packages[!installed_packages])
}

# Packages loading
invisible(lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE))

r <- raster("C:/Users/.../Rainfall_ind2000_rfp25(1).grd")

This gives error
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
In addition: Warning message:
`C:\Users\...\Rainfall_ind2000_rfp25(1).grd' not recognized as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4)


Really you ought to go scream at the data provider to create proper geospatial files with the metadata embedded in a format compatible with GDAL. There should be no excuse for just dumping raw unstructured binary data like this and calling it done.

If you look at the linked Fortran code you can see there's no header info or geographic metadata. The file is simply the 129x135x365 values. These are read in by the Fortran code but not printed.
You can read them in using R with the readBin function. They are 4 byte numeric binary values since 129*135*365*4 is exactly the length of the file in bytes. Check the first few values, these are all -999 which looks like a good "missing value" marker:
> b = readBin("./Rainfall_ind2023_rfp25.grd", what="numeric", size=4, n=129*135*365)
> head(b)
[1] -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999

So, now we have to structure this into a stack of raster layers with the correct extent and CRS and all that, which is mostly given in the text.
Magically this function appears:
readrain <- function(f, ni=129, nj=135, leap=FALSE){
    library(terra)
    if(leap){
        ndays = 366
    }else{
        ndays = 365
    }

    nspatial = ni * nj
    numbers = nspatial * ndays
    filesize = file.info(f)$size
    if(numbers * 4 != filesize){
        stop("File is ",filesize," bytes, expecting ",numbers*4)
    }

    b = readBin(f, what="numeric", size=4, n=numbers)

    layers = lapply( 0:(ndays-1), function(day){
        nday = b[1+(day*nspatial):(nspatial*(day+1) - 1)]
        m = matrix(nday, ni, nj, byrow=TRUE)
        m[m==-999]=NA
        m = m[nrow(m):1,]
        r = rast(m)
        ext(r) = c(66.5, 100.25, 6.5, 38.75)
        crs(r) = "+init=epsg:4326"
        return(r)
    })
    
    rast(layers)
}

Its probably not the most efficient way of doing it but it works, and reading one of these files in isn't too slow:
> r = readrain("./Rainfall_ind2023_rfp25.grd")
> r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 129, 135, 365  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : 66.5, 100.25, 6.5, 38.75  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source(s)   : memory
names       :    lyr.1,    lyr.1,    lyr.1,  lyr.1,    lyr.1,    lyr.1, ... 
min values  : 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.0000,  0.00000, 0.000000, ... 
max values  : 2.159967, 7.696421, 4.255797, 3.6675, 32.30899, 5.726364, ... 
> plot(r[[122]])


Note this might be half a cell off - its not clear if the grid specifies centre points or edges, adjust the extent setting if its not right.
As an exercise you might want to add the dates to the layer names, and auto-detect leap years from the size of the file (use file.info(f)$size and compare with 365*129*135*4 or 366*129*135*4 as a test)
